# Error base de datos SQL

Tags: sql

Ese es el error que me da.

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`osmarentcars`.`itv`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ITV` FOREIGN KEY (`BASTIDOR`) REFERENCES `vehiculos_alquiler` (`BASTIDOR`))

Pongo el código SQL de la creación de la base de datos completa con sus datos y relaciones.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS OSMARENTCARS;
CREATE DATABASE OSMARENTCARS;
USE OSMARENTCARS;





CREATE TABLE MARCA(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(20),
    WEB VARCHAR(30),
    TLF_CONTACTO VARCHAR(12),
    CONSTRAINT PK_MARCA PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
);

INSERT INTO MARCA (DESCRIPCION, WEB, TLF_CONTACTO) VALUES 
("FERRARI", "WWW.FERRARI.COM", "123456789"), 
("FIAT", "WWW.FIAT.COM", "235684791"), 
("FORD", "WWW.FORD.COM", "678678678"),
("HONDA", "WWW.HONDA.COM", "908476321"), 
("HYUNDAI", "WWW.HYUNDAI.COM", "697804157"),
("LAMBORGHINI", "WWW.LAMBORGHINI.COM", "951784662"), 
("MITSUBISHI", "WWW.MITSUBISHI.COM", "987354118"),
("OPEL", "WWW.OPEL.COM", "942668877"),
("RENAULT", "WWW.RENAULT.COM", "958476321"), 
("SEAT", "WWW.SEAT.COM", "697899957"),
("TOYOTA", "WWW.TOYOTA.COM", "951784662"), 
("VOLKSWAGEN", "WWW.VOLKSWAGEN.COM", "987354118");





CREATE TABLE VEHICULOS(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    COLOR VARCHAR(10),
    MATRICULA VARCHAR(7),
    MARCA INT,
    MODELO VARCHAR(50), 
    POTENCIA INT,
    CONSUMO DECIMAL(4,2),
    FECHA_FABRICACION DATE,
    DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(120), 
    CONSTRAINT PK_VEHICULOS PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICULOS FOREIGN KEY (MARCA) REFERENCES MARCA(ID)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICULOS VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", "BLANCO", "2593HBD", 1, "CALIFORNIA", 389, 13.1, "2007/11/03", "Coche CALIFORNIA perfecto para rodar a grandes velocidades."), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", "AMARILLO", "4141HGG", 2, "PUNTO", 85, 7.2, "2008/10/12", "Coche PUNTO de la marca FIAT, modelo muy útil para conducciones en ciudades."), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", "VERDE", "8862DCD", 3, "KA", 87, 8.8, "2004/05/23", "Coche KA poco utilizado de la marca FORD debido a su alto consumo."), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", "METALIZADO", "9876CDS", 4, "JAZZ", 93, 8.8, "2003/10/07", "Monovolumen pequeño con poco consumo de la marca HONDA. Perfecto para familias numerosas."), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "BLANCO", "6295JLS", 5, "I10", 87, 7.9, "2015/12/01", "Edición de HYUNDAI del año 2011 para circular en trayectos largos."), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", "GRIS", "1137HAA", 6, "CENTENARIO", 270, 11.2, "2007/12/06", "Coche CENTENARIO de la marca LAMBORGHINI con una gran potencia."), 
("FERFFER34534533", "ROJO", "6995DDS", 7, "SPACE_STAR", 110, 9.7, "2004/06/04", "Coche SPACE_STAR de la marca MITSUBISHI de mucha potencia y poco consumo."), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", "NARANJA", "1333HAC", 8, "CORSA", 72, 6.4, "2008/12/12", "Coche CORSA de la marca OPEL muy conocido y utilizado en ciudades pequeñas, trayectos cortos."),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", "ROJO", "2522HCC", 9, "TWINGO", 80, 6.7, "2007/11/02", "Coche TWINGO modelo poco conocido dentro de la saga RENAULT."), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", "AMARILLO", "4111HBB", 10, "IBIZA", 88, 7.2, "2008/10/13", "Coche IBIZA de la marca SEAT muy utilizado. Es el modelo más usado junto al TOLEDO."), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", "VERDE", "3062DCA", 11, "AYGO", 103, 7.6, "2004/05/23", "Coche AYGO con mucha potencia y poco consumo. Lo ideal para trayectos largos y rápidos."), 
("LLSERASJK222823", "AZUL", "9223FBF", 12, "TIGUAN", 103, 7.7, "2006/10/11", "Coche TIGUAN, poco familiar en los anuncios de las compañias de televisión."), 
("KEYAO3242342020", "GRIS", "6211BAK", 1, "SERGIO", 356, 12.5, "2002/04/02", "Coche SERGIO de la marca FERRARI con la tercera mayor cantidad de caballos (CV)."), 
("LKOJU234234234J", "BLANCO", "1193HAC", 2, "PANDA", 80, 6.3, "2007/11/04", "Cochce PANDA de la marca FIAT, vehículo de poco espacio pero de muy poco consumo"), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", "ROJO","6945DRE", 3, "FIESTA", 85, 6.8, "2004/06/03", "Coche FIESTA de la marca FORD, muy conocido dentro de esta saga. El más popular entre los clientes de FORD."), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", "NARANJA", "9344AAP", 4, "CIVIC", 90, 7.4, "2001/03/19", "Coche CIVIC dentro de la marca HONDA, muy vistoso por fuera y cómodo por dentro. Gran vehículo para dos personas."),
("MKNOKN38820020F", "ROJO", "0003AGF", 5, "I20", 89, 8.1, "2001/08/02", "Coche I20 de la marca HYUNDAI edición 2013. Muy poco exitoso en ventas."), 
("LKJAWE342422111", "NEGRO", "7667GFR", 6, "HURACAN", 245, 10.7, "2008/10/12", "Coche HURACAN de la marca LAMBORGHINI con poco consumo relativo a su potencia."), 
("KJIOHUHJ6933322", "VERDE",  "3434GHI", 7, "ASX", 139, 9.1, "2004/07/23", "Coche ASX de la marca MITSUBISHI, esperado mayor éxito en su potencia, con sólo 139 caballos."), 
("KJRWQQ0NN4M1119", "AZUL",  "2228CKK", 8, "ZAFIRA", 89, 7.8, "2006/10/11", "Coche ZAFIRA de la marca OPEL. El mejor conocido/popular de esta marca. Pocas ventas en su haber."), 
("ABC3DE559QJK444", "GRIS",  "7188ADS", 9, "MEGANE", 95, 7.6, "2001/03/24", "Coche MEGANE de la marca RENAULT. Con gran cantidad de versiones y muy vendido en España."), 
("BREAOELUHN34397", "NEGRO", "9995FFT", 10, "TOLEDO", 85, 7.0, "2010/12/04", "Coche TOLEDO de la marca SEAT. El segundo en discordia de la saga. Le ha arrebatado el puesto IBIZA."), 
("IUERWIK5688ASDE", "AMARILLO", "4419CII", 11, "YARIS", 100, 7.4, "2005/06/18", "Coche YARIS de la marca TOYOTA. Largo en cuanto a capacidad pero estrecho en cuanto a espacio lateral."), 
("KEEY777ARDD4880", "BLANCO", "6330HDP", 12, "POLO", 100, 7.2, "2009/12/17", "Coche POLO de la marca VOLKSWAGEN. Decepcionante cantidad de ventas debido a sus averías a corto plazo."),
("WEFWEFWF9234242", "BLANCO", "5593HID", 1, "FF", 390, 15.1, "2008/09/05", "Coche FF de la marca FERRARI. El más rápido del mercado con 390 caballos (potencia). Un avión en asfalto."), 
("EFWEFWWER234999", "AMARILLO", "0041HQA", 2, "FREEMONT", 90, 7.9, "2008/11/11", "Coche FREEMONT de la marca FIAT. Gasta muy poco aunque el depósito es muy pequeño."), 
("KPOKPIOHWF56561", "VERDE", "2262DCE", 3, "FOCUS", 85, 9.0, "2004/05/21", "Coche FOCUS de la marca FORD. Exitoso en ventas en el año 2011 en Francia pero con muchos problemas de motor."), 
("ASDASÑLKPOK2342", "METALIZADO", "2876CFS", 4, "NSX", 100, 9.4, "2003/09/19", "Coche NSX de la marca HONDA. Un fracaso en las ventas en España. Poca potencia."), 
("EFEWKPOKPK23424", "BLANCO", "6995JTR", 5, "ELANDRA", 90, 7.9, "2016/04/04", "Coche ELANDRA de la marca HYUNDAI. Bastantes caballos para el poco consumo que tiene."), 
("PKPOK38BVA023J0", "GRIS", "9937HAL", 6, "AVENTADOR", 305, 12.1, "2007/07/28", "Coche AVENTADOR de la marca LAMBORGHINI. Gran potencia en esta marca."), 
("ODKHVIRIRED9839", "GRANATE", "6905DWS", 7, "OUTLANDER", 140, 10.1, "2004/08/18", "Coche OUTLANDER de la marca MITSUBISHI. Desconocido entre los usuarios de MITSUBISHI. Numerosas averías."), 
("ASDERLDI4DJ459W", "NARANJA", "8883HEC", 8, "KARL", 80, 6.6, "2008/12/12", "Coche KARL de la marca OPEL. Poco conocido entre los clientes. A su favor, poco consumo."),
("LKEEKKIQ4822292", "ROJO", "2529DCM", 9, "CLIO", 75, 6.3, "2004/08/29", "Coche CLIO de la marca RENAULT. El que menos consume junto con el PANDA. Muy cómodo para trayectos cortos."), 
("LKEUENCIEMSOWJ3", "AMARILLO", "0011HMM", 10, "LEON", 85, 7.1, "2009/10/13", "Coche LEON de la marca SEAT. Bastante comoda la conducción. Ideal para asfalto liso."), 
("ITJTNRVRNXO0099", "METALIZADO", "8762DNA", 11, "AURIS", 95, 7.4, "2004/05/30", "Coche AURIS de la marca TOYOTA. Ha aumentado notablemente sus ventas en los últimos 4 años."), 
("LAKWYEBDMCIWU2N", "GRIS", "9000FOF", 12, "TOURAN", 115, 8.3, "2007/10/11", "Coche TOURAN de la marca VOLKSWAGEN. Bastante potencia y buena comparación de consumo con sus otros modelos."), 
("LKEUDNMDOJN3333", "GRIS", "8211AAK", 1, "GTC4LUSSO", 370, 14.1, "2002/04/02", "Coche GTC4LUSSO de la marca FERRARI. Modelo muy poco conocido pero con un inconveniente: su alto consumo."), 
("ALAO3AOKEMLEO3K", "BLANCO", "1293HMC", 2, "FLORINO", 95, 6.7, "2007/12/20", "Coche FLORINO de la marca FIAT. Poco conocido entre sus modelos. Punto a favor: alta potencia con poco consumo."), 
("SDFSDFW034KM234", "ROJO", "0045DRA", 3, "MUSTANG", 220, 11.8, "2004/06/03", "Coche MUSTANG de la marca FORD. Muchos caballos y mucho consumo. Dependiendo de la necesidad, sería útil."), 
("OKOKUH88NM9CC04", "NARANJA", "9392AAP", 4, "CLARITY", 135, 9.1, "2000/07/19", "Coche CLARITY de la marca HONDA. La mayor potencia entre todos los Honda. Año 2012 muy favorable a sus ventas."),
("KEIJNRJIJI39991", "ROJO", "8803ASF", 5, "VELOSTER", 95, 8.2, "2001/04/23", "Coche VELOSTER de la marca HYUNDAI. No muy recomendable para trayectos largos debido a su consumo rápido."), 
("ASLOKOENREIRJI3", "NEGRO", "2267AAA", 6, "VENENO", 210, 10.3, "2000/01/01", "Coche VENENO de la marca LAMBORGHINI. Poca capacidad de depósito y alto consumo."), 
("KJUHMKIJWERLW23", "BLANCO", "8834GHI", 7, "MONTERO", 117, 10.0, "2004/07/23", "Coche MONTERO de la marca MITSUBISHI. Suele tener problemas en el motor al cabo de 7 años."), 
("OOKMKIJER394320", "AZUL", "2928CKT", 8, "ASTRA", 85, 7.2, "2006/10/11", "Coche ASTRA. El menos conocido de la saga OPEL. Útil para trayectos largos al tener un consumo menor."), 
("KIEJRWERL222999", "GRIS", "7198BDS", 9, "ZOE", 95, 7.4, "2001/03/24", "Coche ZOE de la marca RENAULT. El menos conocido de la saga RENAULT. Poco consumo."), 
("WASDASDASD92K39", "NEGRO", "0395FGP", 10, "ATECA", 85, 7.4, "2008/12/04", "Coche ATECA de la marca SEAT. Muchos problemas en la conducción debido a su inestabilidad."), 
("K3OK3ORK3ORK333", "AMARILLO", "4819CSI", 11, "VERSO", 110, 7.8, "2006/06/15", "Coche VERSO de la marca TOYOTA. Coche rentable en cuanto al nivel potencia-consumo. Muy usado en terrenos blancos."), 
("KEE22277ARDDC80", "BLANCO", "0000HBP", 12, "JETTA", 145, 9.3, "2009/12/19", "Coche JETTA. De la marca VOLKSWAGEN. Gran cantidad de caballos aunque consumo alto.");





CREATE TABLE VEHICULOS_COMPRA(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    PRECIO_VENTA DECIMAL(7,2),
    FECHA_V_COMPRA DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_VEHICULOS_COMPRA PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICULOS_COMPRA FOREIGN KEY (BASTIDOR) REFERENCES VEHICULOS(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICULOS_COMPRA VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", 12309.00, null), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", 22029.99, "2014/08/12"), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", 19678.54, null), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", 56999.02, null), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", 12589.57, null), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", 89995.86, "2001/08/15"), 
("FERFFER34534533", 18954.59, "2014/02/04"), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", 10095.52, null),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", 14000.03, null), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", 15026.87, "2011/08/15"), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", 19584.33, "2013/09/11"), 
("LLSERASJK222823", 46000.00, "2002/08/13"), 
("KEYAO3242342020", 99999.60, null), 
("LKOJU234234234J", 24000.00, null), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", 16023.23, "2013/01/05"), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", 18000.00, null),
("MKNOKN38820020F", 18050.09, "2012/02/16"), 
("LKJAWE342422111", 64095.65, "2013/01/09"); 





CREATE TABLE VEHICULOS_ALQUILER(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    PRECIO_ALQUILER DECIMAL(7,2),
    FECHA_V_ALQUILER DATE,
    DISPONIBLE BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT PK_VEHICULOS_ALQUILER PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR),
    CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICULOS_ALQUILER FOREIGN KEY (BASTIDOR) REFERENCES VEHICULOS(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICULOS_ALQUILER VALUES 
("KJIOHUHJ6933322", 560.57, null, false), 
("KJRWQQ0NN4M1119", 330.33, "2016/12/01", true), 
("ABC3DE559QJK444", 318.59, null, false), 
("BREAOELUHN34397", 596.06, null, false), 
("IUERWIK5688ASDE", 299.51, "2016/12/02", true), 
("KEEY777ARDD4880", 750.09, "2016/11/27", true),
("WEFWEFWF9234242", 311.80, "2016/12/01", true), 
("EFWEFWWER234999", 795.25, "2016/11/19", true),
("KPOKPIOHWF56561", 300.03, "2016/11/20", true), 
("ASDASÑLKPOK2342", 324.78, "2016/12/02", true), 
("EFEWKPOKPK23424", 316.31, "2016/12/04", true), 
("PKPOK38BVA023J0", 602.25, null, false), 
("ODKHVIRIRED9839", 705.98, null, false), 
("ASDERLDI4DJ459W", 380.58, null, false),
("LKEEKKIQ4822292", 301.84, "2016/12/02", true),    
("LKEUENCIEMSOWJ3", 300.96, null, false),
("ITJTNRVRNXO0099", 301.99, "2016/12/04", true), 
("LAKWYEBDMCIWU2N", 794.84, null, false), 
("LKEUDNMDOJN3333", 425.26, null, false), 
("ALAO3AOKEMLEO3K", 488.39, "2016/12/05", true), 
("SDFSDFW034KM234", 236.21, "2016/12/04", true), 
("OKOKUH88NM9CC04", 295.23, null, false), 
("KEIJNRJIJI39991", 458.00, null, false), 
("ASLOKOENREIRJI3", 456.22, null, false), 
("KJUHMKIJWERLW23", 512.56, null, false), 
("OOKMKIJER394320", 430.02, null, false), 
("KIEJRWERL222999", 499.99, "2016/12/02", true), 
("WASDASDASD92K39", 684.00, null, false), 
("K3OK3ORK3ORK333", 333.33, null, false), 
("KEE22277ARDDC80", 425.00, "2016/11/25", true);





CREATE TABLE ITV(
    BASTIDOR VARCHAR(30),
    FECHA_ITV DATE, 
    RESULTADO BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ITV PRIMARY KEY (BASTIDOR, FECHA_ITV),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ITV FOREIGN KEY (BASTIDOR) REFERENCES VEHICULOS_ALQUILER(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO ITV VALUES 
("JKSFLS23B342988", "2009/18/12", false), 
("JUUS234FWER23RW", "2009/08/11", true), 
("KMOWEMFIF93223F", "2003/05/08", true), 
("FWEF232342AAAAA", "2014/09/14", true), 
("AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "2011/04/10", false), 
("PKOKI9UW45R233E", "2005/08/11", true), 
("FERFFER34534533", "2001/11/18", false), 
("XVXCV8X97XCV989", "2006/08/08", false),
("KH4578KROGKRO44", "2009/08/11", true), 
("LKJOGTUXTD34635", "2013/05/13", false), 
("HGYUGMÑ35636531", "2014/04/25", true), 
("LLSERASJK222823", "2015/08/26", false), 
("KEYAO3242342020", "2016/08/02", false), 
("LKOJU234234234J", "2014/07/03", false), 
("OJIO2J34IOJ2423", "2012/07/05", true), 
("JPKLKMKJH2U3424", "2010/01/11", false),
("MKNOKN38820020F", "2007/04/10", true), 
("LKJAWE342422111", "2014/11/17", false); 





CREATE TABLE CLIENTES(
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20),
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR(30),
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    TLF_CONTACTO VARCHAR(12),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(50),
    CIUDAD VARCHAR(30),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES PRIMARY KEY (DNI) 
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTES VALUES 
("OSMAR", "MAZA LASTRA", "72089193V", "666002138", "C/ Renteria Reyes, 24", "SANTOÑA", "omaza1990@hotmail.com"), 
("RAFA", "MAZA MANTOS", "72084491L", "699002238", "C/ General Davila, 29", "REINOSA", "rafa_@hotmail.es"),  
("ERIK", "PEÑA MATA", "23089103F", "697804174", "C/ La Madrid, 09", "GAMA", "erik_pena_gamacity@gmail.com"), 
("DESI", "UNZUETA FERNANDEZ", "12345678D", "625036676", "C/ Suns Estados, 04", "CASTAÑEDA", "desi9328@outlook.com"), 
("ALEX", "PABLO LAVIN", "98745632A", "666012149", "C/ Brooklyn Nets, 11", "SUANCES", "alex__23@hotmail.es"), 
("NATALIA", "ARIAM SANTOS", "88552244T", "686678888", "C/ Genova Sill, 71", "NOJA", "nata_argos@hotmail.com"), 
("ALFREDO", "RUIZ CASTAÑOS", "14725863S", "616161236", "C/ Ruiz Carral, 34", "CORRALES", "alfredo_macaya@gmail.com"), 
("SUSANA", "ESCARLETA SOZ", "68451277S", "611443789", "C/ Alfonso Rey, 99", "CASTILLO", "susana_soz@hotmail.com"), 
("ADRIAN", "SANCHEZ ESPINOSA", "72089695X", "123456789", "C/ San Pantaleon, 99", "LAREDO", "adrian_laredo@hotmail.com"),  
("CARLOS", "RUIZ MATEOS", "13225217P", "664125877", "C/ Plaza San Antonio, 55", "MERUELO", "carlos__lines@hotmail.com"),
("IDALBA", "MAZA LASTRA", "72089192Q", "666002144", "C/ Renteria Reyes, 24", "SANTOÑA", "idalba__1988@hotmail.com"), 
("ANTONIO", "VALLE RISQUETO", "72086391T", "699442238", "C/ Paseo Pereda, 19", "SANTANDER", "k93k__tesoro@hotmail.com"),  
("SERGIO", "SANTOS MERINO", "24444100A", "697305574", "C/ Jesus de Monasterio, 12", "GAMA", "hay_que_ser_felizzzz@gmail.com"), 
("ALFREDO", "LILIETA MENENDEZ", "12345678S", "625136076", "C/ Avenida San Pedro, 85", "CASTRO", "alfre_liliiii@outlook.com"), 
("SARA", "SANCHEZ LAVIN", "68795632P", "66600214", "C/ Los Angeles, 10", "SOMO", "sara_albo_colin@hotmail.com"), 
("SOFIA", "ARIAM GOMEZ", "86052244T", "616678338", "C/ Gaditano Ole, 02", "GUEMES", "sofia_gran_hermano@hotmail.com"), 
("ROCIO", "RUIZ FERNANDEZ", "19925863P", "61616698", "C/ San Cristobal, 02", "CIRIEGO", "rociito_la_kuki@gmail.es"), 
("CARLOS ALBERTO", "RUIZ SAINZ", "68221277S", "611444777", "C/ Sigtes, 93", "CASTILLO", "carlos_ruizz@hotmail.com"), 
("IVAN", "ARGOS OCERIN", "72999695F", "103456759", "C/ Avenida Central, 29", "ISLA", "ivan_argos_gol@hotmail.es"),
("CARLOS", "SETIEN FYB", "73089663H", "662456751", "C/ Reina Victoria, 121", "SANTANDER", "carlos_s@fyb.es"),
("SARAY", "LAVIN SIERRA", "41002295X", "103400009", "C/ Sierra de los Corderos, 11", "REINOSA", "saray__@hotmail.es"),
("CARLA", "MAZA BARROJO", "77772486A", "893663434", "C/ Cisneros, 06", "SANTANDER", "carla__maza_pri@outlook.es"),
("SIRO", "ABAD MERINO", "99225217Z", "633125077", "C/ Plaza San Mateo, 53", "TORRELAVEGA", "siro__abad@hotmail.com");





CREATE TABLE CLIENTES_COMPRA(
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    ID_VEHICULO VARCHAR(30),
    FECHA_C_COMPRA DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES_COMPRA PRIMARY KEY (DNI, ID_VEHICULO, FECHA_C_COMPRA),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_COMPRA1 FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES CLIENTES(DNI),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_COMPRA2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_VEHICULO) REFERENCES VEHICULOS(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTES_COMPRA VALUES 
("72089193V", "JKSFLS23B342988", "2009/11/19"),
("72084491L", "JUUS234FWER23RW", "2009/12/13"),
("23089103F", "KMOWEMFIF93223F", "2009/05/11"),
("12345678D", "FWEF232342AAAAA", "2009/04/30"),
("98745632A", "AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "2005/01/03"),
("88552244T", "PKOKI9UW45R233E", "2008/01/13"),
("14725863S", "FERFFER34534533", "2004/11/06"),
("72089695X", "XVXCV8X97XCV989", "2012/11/06"),
("68451277S", "KH4578KROGKRO44", "2015/06/08"),
("12345678S", "KEYAO3242342020", "2009/05/19"),
("68795632P", "LKOJU234234234J", "2005/05/23"),
("86052244T", "LKJAWE342422111", "2003/09/23"),
("19925863P", "OJIO2J34IOJ2423", "2014/01/29"),
("68221277S", "JPKLKMKJH2U3424", "2014/02/21"),
("72089192Q", "MKNOKN38820020F", "2010/02/21");





CREATE TABLE CLIENTES_ALQUILER(
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    ID_VEHICULO VARCHAR(30),
    FECHA_C_ALQUILER DATE,
    FECHA_C_ENTREGA_SUPUESTA DATE,
    FECHA_C_ENTREGA_REAL DATE, 
    FIANZA INT(4),
    ESTADO_DEVOLUCION VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES_ALQUILER PRIMARY KEY (DNI, ID_VEHICULO, FECHA_C_ALQUILER),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_ALQUILER1 FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES CLIENTES(DNI),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTES_ALQUIILER2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_VEHICULO) REFERENCES VEHICULOS(BASTIDOR)
);

INSERT INTO CLIENTES_ALQUILER VALUES 
("72089193V", "KEE22277ARDDC80", "2009/09/19", "2009/12/19", "2009/12/19", 47, "Neumaticos desgastados."),
("12345678D", "KEE22277ARDDC80", "2011/10/11", "2011/12/13", "2011/12/13", 47, "Maletero estropeado."),
("72999695F", "KEE22277ARDDC80", "2009/03/04", "2009/03/06", "2009/03/07", 47, "Volante muy rigido."),
("68795632P", "KEE22277ARDDC80", "2013/04/29", "2013/05/17", "2013/05/17", 47, "Neumaticos desgastados."),
("72089193V", "JKSFLS23B342988", "2011/12/02", "2011/12/19", "2011/12/19", 47, "Tapacubos rotos."),
("72084491L", "JUUS234FWER23RW", "2011/01/01", "2011/01/09", "2011/01/12", 250, "Olor a húmedo, goteras en la zona trasera."),
("72084491L", "JUUS234FWER23RW", "2011/06/28", "2011/06/29", "2011/06/29", 250, "Tiene la tapiceria estropeada."),
("23089103F", "KMOWEMFIF93223F", "2008/12/01", "2008/12/19", "2008/12/21", 290, null),
("12345678D", "FWEF232342AAAAA", "2003/09/10", "2003/09/11", "2003/09/20", 199, null),
("98745632A", "AAAA3AFKGUEG339", "2003/09/02", "2003/09/19", "2003/09/19", 300, null),
("88552244T", "PKOKI9UW45R233E", "2002/12/09", "2002/12/19", "2002/12/19", 267, true),
("14725863S", "FERFFER34534533", "2002/09/10", "2002/09/19", "2002/09/26", 136, "Mal funcionamiento del aire acondicionado."),
("72089695X", "XVXCV8X97XCV989", "2005/09/06", "2005/09/09", "2005/09/10", 68, null);





CREATE TABLE PENALIZACION(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DIAS INT,
    IMPORTE DECIMAL(7,2),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PENALIZACION PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
);

INSERT INTO PENALIZACION (DIAS, IMPORTE) VALUES 
(2,39.45), 
(5,74.62), 
(10,128.41), 
(14,274.62), 
(21,409.03), 
(28,589.99), 
(30,602.71);
```

Comment: ese error es de duplicidad de las id a las que haces referencias en tus foreign key... revisaste que no esten como `unique`

Comment: en ninguna pongo "unique", revisé el código y las relaciones y yo lo veo bien. Y ninguna clave primaria se repite por tabla...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se causa ya que intentas insertar datos referenciales a una tabla `vehiculos_alquiler` que no existen en dicha tabla. Es por eso que al hacer una `FK` debe existir el otro valor en la otra tabla para insertarlo de forma correcta:

```
INSERT INTO ITV VALUES ("EFWEFWWER234999", "2009/18/12", false);
INSERT INTO ITV VALUES ("ASLOKOENREIRJI3", "2009/18/12", false);
```

Prueba con estos datos como ejemplo (que estan presentes en tu tabla `vehiculos_alquiler` y veras que funciona.

Comment: Gracias a todos. Ya vi que algun bastidor de la tabla ITV no estaba en la tabla vehiculos_alquiler.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te está pasando es que estás intentando introducir números de bastidores en la tabla `itv` que no existen en `vehiculos_alquiler`.